# Мой пример и его ошибки

Tags: java

Класс `Cat`

```
public class Cat {
    String name;

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Бег");
    }
}
```

Класс `Tiger`

```
public class Tiger extends Cat {

    String name;

    public Tiger(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Тигр бежит");
    }
}
```

Класс `Lion`

```
public class Lion extends Cat {
    String name;

    public Lion(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Лев бежит");
    }
}
```

Класс `Cheetah`

```
public class Cheetah extends Cat{
    String name;

    public Cheetah(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Гепард бежит");
    }
}
```

Класс `Test`

```
 public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Lion l1 = new Lion("Лев Вася");
            Tiger t1 = new Tiger("Тигр Тимоша");
            Cheetah c1 = new Cheetah("Гепард Филя");
            Doctor d1 = new Doctor();
            d1.healCat(l1);
            d1.healCat(t1);
        }
    }
```

Класс `Doctor`

```
public class Doctor {
    public void healCat(Cat cat) {
        System.out.println("Пациент" + cat.name + "здоров");
        cat.run();
    }
}
```

Пришла такая идея сделать в классе `Doctor` в методе `healCat` команду `System.out.println("Пациент" + cat.name + "здоров");`
Чтобы выводило для каждого объекта свой `name`. Но после создания для всех классов наследников конструктора начались проблемы с кодом. В каждом наследнике подчеркивается красной линией и пишет: `There is no default constructor available in Cat`. Как сделать так чтобы все имена выводились в методе `healCat`.

Comment: Поскольку в классе Cat есть только конструктор с параметром (name), то все его наследники должны его вызывать. Вам надо либо в Cat добавить конструктор по-умолчанию ( public Cat(){} ), либо во всех наследниках в конструкторе первой строкой добавить вызов super(name);

Comment: А можно по подробнее из-за чего это? Я поправил и теперь работает

Comment: По-умолчанию, если конструктор в классе не прописан, то подразумевается пустой. В наследниках при создании вызываются все конструкторы родителей, и если пустого конструктора нет, необходимо передавать параметры.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш класс Cat является родительским классом для всех остальных классов, описывающих животных. Все дело в конструкторе, который вы создали в классе Cat. Дело в том, что компилятор автоматически добавляет конструктор без параметров в любой класс , но только до тех пор, пока вы не добавите конструктор с параметрами, что и произошло в классе Cat. Теперь все ваши классы, которые наследуются от клааса Cat, должны в своем конструкторе вызвать конструктор родителя, поскольку он теперь один. Вы должны помнить, что у класса родителя и дочерних классов отношение is a, т.е. дочерний класс всегда является своим супер классом. В вашем случае в супер классе есть конструктор, а конструктор служит для создания экземпляра класса и инициализации переменных. Конструктор в вашем классе Cat  всего один, это значит , что путей создать экземпляр данного класса, кроме как вызвать единственный конструктор, просто не существует. Отношение is a дочернего класса теперь вынуждает все дочерние классы вызывать данный конструктор суперкласса, ведь другим путем создать объект теперь невозможно. Посему вам нужно переписать свой класс Cat, добавив геттер для имени.

```
public class Cat {

    private String name;

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Бег");
    }
}
```

А все дочерние классы написать таким образом, чтобы в конструкторе было обращение к конструктору класса родителя (super(name)).

```
public class Tiger extends Cat {

    public Tiger(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Тигр бежит");
    }
}
```

При этом переменная String name в каждом классе уже не нужна, ведь она есть у родителя.

Класс Doctor теперь будет выглядеть так (обращение к переменной через гетер)

```
public class Doctor {

    public void healCat(Cat cat) {
        System.out.println("Пациент " + cat.getName() + " здоров");
        cat.run();
    }
}
```